# Extracting HTTP link(http://) for the string in VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, url

I have the following column values in my table

Sample values:

1. Check out ABC Group Blog post about XYZ Today! http://blog.saedg.org/
2. 'Join ABC in urging the county to help create new jobs and economic opportunities for XYZCounty. http://starabcnet.com/news/science/environment/article_4b3d2f7e-96c6-5007-a036-b4613250755e.html

I want to have 2 variables having the links and content separate – example:

1. Var1 = Check out ABC Group Blog post about XYZ Today!
   Var2 = http://blog.saedg.org/
2. Var1 = Join ABC in urging the county to help create new jobs and economic opportunities for XYZCounty
   Var2 = http://starabcnet.com/news/science/environment/article_4b3d2f7e-96c6-5007-a036-b4613250755e.html

I guess it can be done via String funcions or regular expression.

Comment: Does the URL always follow the rest of the string and is the last thing inside the value?

Comment: aniket, please accept answers on your other questions by ticking the check mark to the left of answers that have helped you in your other questions. The “0% accept mark” is putting potential helpers off. Also, don’t forget to *upvote* helpful answers.

Comment: Agreed, you will get more help if you accept and upvote helpful answers. In any case, I have given you something to point you in the right direction...

Comment: Hello there,Yes the URL will follow the rest of the string. Sorry for the late response.Sometimes there is not String only the URL present.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
' This is the regex that is used to get the addresses
Public Shared URL As New Regex("(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])", RegexOptions.Compiled)

' URL.Matches returns a collection of results that you can iterate through eg:
for each ele in URL.Matches("INPUT STRING")
    ' do something with each link that you get 
    ' like removing them from the input string
next
```

Comment: Hello,
I want to store the URL and String part in seperate variable.
So I perform Split operation in for next loop right

Comment: I would perform a `String.Remove` and remove the `ele` variable from your main string. You can then perform a `String.Concat` to append it back on to the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Can you separate the column in two different columns? Like, "Message" and "Link" for example.

If you can not do that, assuming the Http is always in the end of string and there is no other reference to HTTP:// in the string, you can get the string after "HTTP://".

Look at IndexOf and Substring methods of string in VB.NET.

Something like this (I didn't test):

```
string url = var.SubString(var.IndexOf("http"))
```

Comment: HTTP is always at the end of String. When we have substring we need to specify the length. Thats is where the problem arises

Comment: No you don't. If you don't specify the length, the result will be the start point until the end of string. Use this: Public Function Substring(ByVal startIndex As Integer) As String